# Laravel websockets - Starting the WebSocket server on port 6001

Tags: laravel, websocket

estoy intentando poner en marchar un servidor webcokets en mi app de laravel, cuando ejecuto :

```
php artisan websockets:serve
```

se queda pillado en este momento:

```
php artisan websockets:serve
Starting the WebSocket server on port 6001...
```

He seguido tutoriales como:
https://www.laraveltip.com/laravel-websocket-como-utilizar-websockets-con-php/ pero no termina de funcionar .

**AppServiceProvider.php**

```
    'providers' => [
....
        //Real time
        App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class
...
]
```

**BoradCasting.php**

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
//                'useTLS' => true,
                'host'=>'127.0.0.1',
                'port'=>'6001',
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: Pues no entiendo muy bien cuál es tu error. Que se quede ahí quiere decir que te funciona perfecto. Ahora si no te muestra nada más luego de haber ejecutado un evento, pues quiere decir que tienes problemas de comunicación entre tu vista y tu backend.

Comment: podrías decirnos que no esta funcionando ?

Comment: Pues que se queda pillado arrancando el websockets.  Si funcionara me debería dejar entrar en la parte de afmin de websocket

Comment: Como te digo, si en tu terminal muestra eso, es porque el socket arranca, ahora si no puedes acceder a la ruta para el panel, es porque te falta algo de los pasos a configurar o tienes un problema con tu dominio.

Comment: Pero me deberia de dejar entrar en `/websockets` no ? para controlar los sockets y verificar q esta ok

Comment: si esa es la ruta que has colocado, nunca vas a acceder, porque la ruta es `laravel-websocket`

Answer (score 0):

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

La respuesta dada anteriormente sí permite acceder a la url, pero al intentar conectar lanza un error. En mi caso, uso Laravel 10 + Docker, por lo que para que se conecte correctamente y funcione he seguido las instrucciones de [este artículo](https://dterumalai.medium.com/add-laravel-websockets-to-sail-in-5-mins-71c8d9ceeb8a). Si se siguen todos pasos no será necesario ejecutar el comando `php artisan websockets:serve`, ya que al modificar el fichero **supervisord.conf** en docker/[versión que se esté usando según docker-compose.yml] se inicia el servidor Laravel Websockets automáticamente al iniciar el contenedor.

**FIN ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Por si alguien llega a esta consulta:

Que el mensaje en consola se quede en `Starting the WebSocket sercer on port 6001...` es el funcionamiento normal, en mi experiencia el mensaje **no cambia** si los websockets funcionan.

Yo, tras ejecutar todos los pasos de instalación listados en [esta web](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/installation), me enfrenté al mismo problema y lo solucioné modificando el fichero **.env** antes de ejecutar el comando `php artisan websockets:serve` añadiendo lo siguiente:

```
BROADCAST_PUSHER=pusher 
PUSHER_APP_ID=[un id] 
PUSHER_APP_KEY=[una key] 
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=[un código] 
PUSHER_HOST= 
PUSHER_PORT=443 
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1
```

Dos cosas a tener en cuenta:

1. Fíjense bien en la url en la que se está ejecutando Laravel. En mi caso, es `http://127.0.0.1`, sin puerto. Por tanto, debido a mi configuración, la url a la que tengo que dirigirme para comprobar si los websockets están funcionando será `http://127.0.0.1/laravel-websockets`.
2. Si modifican el fichero **.env** recuerden reiniciar el servidor de backend para que se tengan en cuenta los cambios.

Espero que esta respuesta les ayude.

Comment: Obviamente si se están utilizando variables de entorno para la configuración de algo (sea sockets o cualquier cosa) es necesario tener dichas variables de entorno configuradas! Puede usarse un .env o tenerlas literalmente en variables de entorno del sistema, pero en algún lado tienen que estar, php no hace magia